# PDF Viewer Plugin for Android lower versions

Tags: angular, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Hi I am working in angular project, where i need to show a pdf file from API. i am using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer to show the pdf. but its only working on android 8+ devices.

i need to show this pdf in android lower versions like android 4,5,6. can anyone provide me a supported plugin to show the pdf in lower versions of android.

the api response returns binary data, i converted into BLOB then displays it as pdf, also i can store the file as pdf in mobile local storage too. Need to show the pdf only in lower version, guide me if anyone.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without additional context, I can only guess. I suppose it's a JavaScript error because your older devices don't support current ECMAScript. You can try to activate the ES5 version of the JavaScript files, and you can try to find a polyfill.